# gzip compression disabled (install ext/zlib)

Tags: php, apache, zlib, rhel

Below is the php info of our server (Refer image Configure commands).As we can see that `--with-zlib-dir=/usr` is present in the configure commands required to install Zlib for php.

[Configure Command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPY8R.png)
But Zlib is still shown as disabled on the PHAR 
[Zlib disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPAg7.png)

I have tried changing on php.ini [Changes on php.ini](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beopk.png) and even apache24.conf but still not working. Server is RHEL.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if 'ZLib Support' is 'enabled' in your phpinfo() page.

   If `ZLib Support` doesn't esists in your phpinfo() page, it's sure that zlib extension was not compiled.
2. Upload your config.log file here.

   Try find zlib check result in the config.log file may help answer your question.

Comment: Zlib support is disabled. I will check on that config.log and let you know . Thank you